# Keeping an Excel COM object alive

Tags: excel, com, com-interop, excel-interop, comexception

I'm currently using the **Excel 2003 Interop** mechanism to manipulate some **Ranges**.

Sometimes I store some of the ranges in my **addin**, as properties of a class, but when I try to access them at a later time the **COM objects** are sometimes, randomly, invalid, and each property of the **COM objects** throws a "**COMException**" when I try to access them.

I have been said that there is no strong link between the objects **Excel** allocates and the objects the addin is using : so the "true" **Range objects** could be freed by **Excel** at any time, even if from a **.Net/C#** perspective I still have a reference to them.

**So, I was wondering if there is any way to keep my Range objects alive to use them later in a safe manner ?**

Remark : I could use a workaround like storing **strings** that would represent the **Ranges**, e.g. "A1", instead of the **Ranges** themselves but this would make the code less clean.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> I have been said that there is no strong link between the objects Excel allocates and the objects the addin is using

That is referring to the fact that Excel uses "Flyweights". Excel does not use COM internally; it creates COM wrappers to its internal structures (I think of them as "views") as needed to serve requests by a COM client (be it an Add-in, VBA or an external application).

> ... the "true" Range objects could be freed by Excel at any time

I wouldn't say "at any time".

Once you get a `Range` object, or any other COM object, the COM object will stay available until released (in the COM sense - calling `IUnknown::Release()` for each `AddRef()`).

*However*, if you hold a COM object and the underlying structures cease to exist, the COM object does become invalid. What else could it do?

Lets say that you hold onto a `Range` and the user deletes the worksheet where the Range was located. What do you think should happen? It's not like Excel is going to throw a message box saying *"sorry, you cannot delete the worksheet because some code wants to hold onto it"*. If the user deletes the data, Excel will comply and the `Range` object will have to cope. You Add-in just needs to be prepared for that possibility. If you Add-in provides formulas, have them return #REF, etc.

I don't think there is anyway to proactively detect this. I checked to see if there is some kind of IsValid(myRange) method somewhere, but I didn't see any.

Anyway, it's unlikely it would be very useful; many commands could result on [windows] messages being processed and anytime that happens outside code could run at unsuspecting times and invalidate the range on you. You really have to catch the error as it happens, and 'punt' appropriately.

Maybe you're right. It might as well be "*at any time*". But it's not random. Someone has to go and muck with the range.

Incidentally, I wouldn't try to outsmart the situation. Saving the range reference text will only result in the AddIn acting on a different set of data that the user intended. The "correct" thing to do is to "fail gracefully".

Comment: thanks for this complete answer. My problem is that the ranges in question are never deleted nor moved by the user. Each range corresponds to a column, and only the cells values in the columns are modified.

Comment: That does sound weird. How are the cells modified? Just edited by hand? Do you know what's the exact exception/HRESULT you are getting?

Comment: Yes the cells are only modified by hand by the user. I don't remember the exact error code, but storing only some string references instead of the "Range" themselves has fixed the issue, does not affect too heavily the code and does not seem to have side-effects on performance.